# MySQL - How can I make column be a sum of the two other columns from different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL and databases overall. Is it possible two create a table where a column is a sum of two other columns from two other tables. 
For instance if I have database `Books :

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `book_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `book_author` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `book_co-authors` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `book_edition` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `book_creation` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `book_amount` int(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Amount of book copies in both University libraries'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can make column `book_amount` be a sum of the two `book_amount` columns from `library1` and `library2` tables where `book_id = book_id`?
Library1 :

```
CREATE TABLE `library1` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `available_amount` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: So all the other columns are there in tables `library1` and `library2` with samme datatypes?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can define a column with whatever type you want, so long as it's valid, and then populate it as you will with data from other tables. This is generally called "denormalizing" as under ideal circumstances you'll want that data stored in other tables and computed on demand so there's never a chance of your saved value and the source data falling out of sync.

You can also define a `VIEW` which is like a saved query that behaves as if it's a table. This can do all sorts of things, like dynamically query other tables, and presents the result as a column. A "materialized view" is something some databases support where the view is automatically updated and saved based on some implicit triggers. A non-materialized view is slower, but in your case the speed difference might not be a big deal.

So you have options in how you represent this.

One thing to note is that you should use `INT` as a default "integer" field, not wonky things like `INT(100)`. The number for integer fields specifies how many significant digits you're expecting, and as `INT` can only store at most 11 this is wildly out of line.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, however there are a few ways to achieve what you're after.

Either create a psuedo column in your select clause which adds the other two columns

```
select *, columna+columnb AS `addition` from books
```

Don't forget to swap out `columna` and `columnb` to the name of the columns, and `addition` to the name you'd like the psuedo column to have.

Alternatively, you could use a view to auto add the psuedo field in the same way. However, views do not have indexes, so performing lookups in them and joining them can get rather slow very easily.

You could also use triggers to set the values upon insert and update, or simply calculate the value within the language that inserts into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will work if `library1` and `library2` table has similar schema as table `books`:

```
Insert into books
    select l1.book_id,
           l1.book_name,
           l1.book_authors,
           l1.book_co_authors,
           l1.book_edition,
           l1.book_creation,
           (l1.book_amount + l2.book_amount)
    from library1 l1
    inner join library2 l2
    on l1.book_id = l2.book_id
    group by l1.book_id
    ;
```